# Removing from list

Tags: java, algorithm, list

**NOTE**: In the example above, I cannot override equals method because it's already used for another purpose.

I have the following classes:

```
public class A{ }
```

and

```
public class B{
    private A a;
    //GET, SET
}
```

Now, I have the following controller:

```
public class ControllerOfMine{

    private List<B> bs;

    public List<B> remove(List<A> as){
        if(as.isEmpty()){  //1, Dumb if
            return bs;
        }
        List<B> result = new ArrayList<B>();
        for(B item : bs){
            for(A aItem : as){
                if(item.getA().equals(aItem)){
                    continue;
                } else {
                    result.add(item);
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, my question is how to avoid that dumb checking for `as.isEmpty()`. I think my algroithm is not too good.

Comment: Are you doing a "true" remove from your List?  Looks to me that you're returning a copy of the removed results.

Comment: First your question title has nothing to do with what you're asking. Second, why do you consider that check dumb?

Comment: It's not clear *what* your requirement is. If you specify a list of 'A's to remove and they're not present, you'll put duplicate 'B's in your return list. Is that what you want ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew No, I asked about effective computation

Comment: If `equals()` is used for anything other than checking conceptual equality (that is, will my code behave in exactly the same way if fed any of the instances that are `equal()` to each other), that's a big no-no.

Comment: You want to get rid of a single line that costs you nothing? Why? You should consider other data structures that are more appropriate for this sort of things, for example some kind of Set with constant find and remove time.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I could consider Set, but don't see how it maight be helpful.

Comment: @stella Hint: create a `HashMap<B,A>` from your list first.

Comment: Since you did not tell anything about the wider context, it's difficult to propose something more specific than "Use data structures with O(1)-remove if you remove often". If you really want to have ordered lists, then your solution is optimal. I don't understand why this single line bothers you at all. It costs literally *nothing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the inner loop by an O(1) lookup operation.
Something along these lines:

```
public class ControllerOfMine{

    private List<B> bs;

    public List<B> remove(List<A> as){
        if (as.isEmpty()) return bs;

        HashSet<A> quickLookup = new HashSet<A>();
        quickLookup.addAll(as);
        List<B> result = new ArrayList<B>();
        for (B b: bs) {
          if (!quickLookup.contains(b.getA())) {
            result.add(b);
          }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

The single line at the beginning of the method costs almost nothing, it's O(1). The translation into a `HashSet` is O(n), but all subsequent `contains` queries are amortized `O(1)`. This *could* run faster under certain circumstances (iterating through lists is actually pretty fast, they must have certain length before a `HashSet` begins to outperform them in lookup operations).